# STM32f103 Clock Configuration RCC_DeInit() problem

Tags: stm32

### In this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535777/stm32f103c8-wont-start?noredirect=1#comment1385750_535777) I realized that the clock configuration is my main problem which some time works and some time doesn't. Based on my search a comprehensive explanation about clock configuration is missing. So I started this topic exclusively about clock configuration. Getting the first minus before reading this topic and comparing it with the old one is not fair.

Here is my MCU clock configuration:

```
void CLOCK(void){
    
    //RCC_DeInit(); 
    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);
    RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    while(RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp()==ERROR);
    
    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);
    
    RCC_PLLCmd(DISABLE);
    RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSE_Div1,9);
    RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
    
    while(RCC_GetFlagStatus( RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY)!=SET);
    
    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);
    
    RCC_ClockSecuritySystemCmd(ENABLE);
    RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);
    
    
    RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1); // HCLK is = SYSCLK 
    RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);  // PCLK is 30MHZ, and timer3 clk should be 2x PCLK ( 60 MHZ)
    RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);     

    
    while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08);
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

}
```

I have some problems and questions:

1)By using,"RCC_DeInit(); " in the first line of my Clock function, it reduces my final speed instead of switching to the PLL and make the final speed high, why?
2)In a previous board that I have, these lines works fine to make my MCU active on PLL, but in my new MCU it doesn't work properly.

```
    RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    while(RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp()==ERROR);

    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_0);
```

However, when I changed the FLASH_Latency_0 to FLASH_Latency_2 it works fine,why?

3)How to have a safe mode, when the output crystal or PLL failed, the MCU works with the internal 8Mhz and make the CPU clock 72Mhz?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like it should be a clarifying edit as you learn more about the problem in your existing unanswered, unresolved question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535777/stm32f103c8-wont-start where your investigation/comments seemed headed in this direction and specifically mentioned this clock issue as the apparent cause, rather than a new question

Comment: Thank you Chris, I think question should be to the point because in that post I have mentioned my problem (and it was not about the clock configuration)and this question is more general.

Comment: this should probably be on stackoverflow...

Comment: are you wanting to set the clock based on the pll one time after reset?  the part starts with the internal clock by default then you have to work your way to using the pll.  If you want to later change the pll then of course you have to go back to hsi or hse then back onto the pll...

Comment: is there a reason for going 72mhz?

Comment: Thank you old_timer for your cooperation, after reset I need to set my clock to HSE and if HSE failed it starts HSI for getting 72Mhz, My USART speed is about 2.5Mb I need to have a high speed MCU.

Comment: 1) Just debug what the library does at RCC_deinit if it causes problems. 2) Check you have latest CubeF1 library, have read the release erratas. It might depends on MCU batch or silicon revision, so check MCU erratas. 2.5) You can't run at 72 MHz and latency 0, you need latency 2. Read the manuals if you want to initialize the MCU, normally you let CubeMX to generate startup code that simply works. 3) Change the code so that it does not care about clock source or PLL lock. But then code might run unstably, and all timing could be too much off for UART and USB comms etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a complete working example of setting the STM32F103C8T6 to 72MHz using an external 8MHz.

In either approach you need to dig into the actual code and see what registers and what bits are being touched in what order.  And compare that to the documentation for the part.

First guess is it appears you are overclocking the system. Last step in clock init is selecting the PLL as the clock source, not in the middle.  Or maybe I am misunderstanding the code, visibility into the library code was not provided.

Normally you pick the slowest clock speed on an mcu that your system level design can support.  But if you need to max this out you can try the code below, everything you need is there but the toolchain (no libraries, no headers).

Understanding that some mcus you can brick if you mess with the clocks and fail.  The STM32's fortunately have a boot0/1 pin solution but you hardwired those without jumpers or left them floating.

You should not have started a new question you should have continued the previous one with additional edits to the question (not removing anything from the question, just adding more to the end).

How did you verify that nothing works on that board?  For example

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
}
```

flash.s

```
.thumb
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.thumb_func
reset:
    add r1,#1
    b reset
```

build

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m3 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o -o flash.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D flash.elf > flash.list
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary flash.elf flash.bin
```

examine vector table (well the whole program)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000
 8000004:   08000009

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   3101        adds    r1, #1
 800000a:   e7fd        b.n 8000008 <reset>
```

Looks good.

Write and test it using openocd

```
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000008 msp: 0x20001000
> flash write_image erase flash.elf
auto erase enabled
device id = 0x20036410
flash size = 64kbytes
wrote 1024 bytes from file flash.elf in 0.115443s (8.662 KiB/s)
> reset
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000008 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r1
r1 (/32): 0x008C92A3
> resume
> halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000008 msp: 0x20001000
> reg r1
r1 (/32): 0x016BAB2E
>
```

r1 is counting, so the flash did get loaded and the program is running.

Assuming the above works (naturally, do not move forward if the above does not work).

A working example on a blue pill (external crystal and led on pc13)

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
}
```

flash.s

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b .
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define GPIOCBASE 0x40011000

#define RCC_BASE 0x40021000
#define RCC_APB2ENR (RCC_BASE+0x18)
#define RCC_APB1ENR (RCC_BASE+0x1C)
#define RCC_CR      (RCC_BASE+0x00)
#define RCC_CFGR    (RCC_BASE+0x04)
#define FLASH_ACR   0x40022000

static void hse_init ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(RCC_CR);
    ra=ra|1<<16;
    PUT32(RCC_CR,ra);
    while(1) if(GET32(RCC_CR)&(1<<17)) break;
    if(1)
    {
        ra=GET32(RCC_CFGR);
        ra&=~(0x3<<0);
        ra|= (0x1<<0);
        PUT32(RCC_CFGR,ra);
        while(1) if((GET32(RCC_CFGR)&0xF)==0x5) break;
    }
}
    
static void pll_init ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    //hse_init();
    ra=0;
    ra|= 0x7<<24;
    ra|= 0x0<<22;
    ra|= 0x7<<18;
    ra|= 0x0<<17;
    ra|= 0x1<<16;
    ra|= 0x0<<14;
    ra|= 0x0<<11;
    ra|= 0x4<< 8;
    ra|= 0x0<< 4;
    PUT32(RCC_CFGR,ra);

    ra=GET32(RCC_CR);
    ra=ra|1<<24;
    PUT32(RCC_CR,ra);
    while(1) if(GET32(RCC_CR)&(1<<25)) break;

    PUT32(FLASH_ACR,0x2);

    ra=GET32(RCC_CFGR);
    ra&=~(0x3<<0);
    ra|= (0x2<<0);
    PUT32(RCC_CFGR,ra);
    while(1) if((GET32(RCC_CFGR)&0xF)==0xA) break;
}
void blinker ( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rx;

    for(rx=0;rx<n;rx++)
    {
        PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x10,1<<(13+ 0));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
        PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x10,1<<(13+16));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }
}

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    hse_init();

    ra=GET32(RCC_APB2ENR);
    ra|=1<<4; //enable port c
    PUT32(RCC_APB2ENR,ra);
    //config
    ra=GET32(GPIOCBASE+0x04);
    ra&=~(3<<20);   //PC13
    ra|=  1<<20;    //PC13
    ra&=~(3<<22);   //PC13
    ra|=  0<<22;    //PC13
    PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x04,ra);

    blinker(5);
    pll_init();
    blinker(50000);
    return(0);
}
```

build

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m3 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary notmain.elf notmain.bin
```

examine vector table

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f830   bl  800006c <notmain>
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <reset+0x4>
```

Looks good.

Write to chip

```
halt
flash write_image erase notmain.elf
reset
```

And watch the led, a few slow, the rest fast.

If your crystal is not working then dont select it.

```
Bit 16 PLLSRC
```

HSI is 8MHz so this would make it 36MHz if you only change that bit (so you will want to change your multiplier).  But you can see if your pcb and the external clock work.  Or you can:

```
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    ra=GET32(RCC_APB2ENR);
    ra|=1<<4; //enable port c
    PUT32(RCC_APB2ENR,ra);
    //config
    ra=GET32(GPIOCBASE+0x04);
    ra&=~(3<<20);   //PC13
    ra|=  1<<20;    //PC13
    ra&=~(3<<22);   //PC13
    ra|=  0<<22;    //PC13
    PUT32(GPIOCBASE+0x04,ra);

    blinker(5);
    hse_init();
    blinker(50000);
    return(0);
}
```

And see if it is stuck forever on one of the polling loops. Naturally before attempting to use the PLL one would test the external clock works.  And then move on to a test that the PLL works and then move on to more tests and eventually the product firmware.

Compare the steps and settings with your init as you dig into the library code to see what it does (if this is code from the mcu vendor, it is pretty scary stuff, that is why I do not go near it).

From reset the system is using HSI so long as you do not have the factory bootloader in the path for some reason (you do not).

Bring up HSE if you wish, you do not have to switch the system to HSE, it just
needs to be up to feed the PLL.

The reset value on CFGR2 is the HSE as the PLL clock source, so do not need to touch that.

It is safe to configure the PLL settings since the PLL is not enabled (on reset) nor selected.  You can choose to write the CFGR in one shot or read-modify-write so long as it is ONE READ, many modifications, and ONE WRITE.

```
ra=GET32(RCC_CFGR);
ra&=~(0x7<<24);
ra|= (0x7<<24);
ra&=~(0x1<<22);
ra|= (0x0<<22);
ra&=~(0x7<<11);
ra|= (0x0<<11);
ra&=~(0x7<<8);
ra|= (0x4<<8);
ra&=~(0xF<<4);
ra|= (0x0<<4);
```

Before selecting the PLL have to slow down the flash controller. (and the rest of the system clock division)

Turn the PLL on, wait for ready.

Select the PLL as the system clock and poll for that status to indicate it switched.

It is a really good idea to have one or a few unknowns at a time.  Basically software is an unknown, working through this code and something as delicate as clock init on a blue pill then later moving that code to your card (a new unknown).  To be fair the blue pills are pretty low quality, I buy them 5 or 10 at a time and expect and have some show up DOA.  And of those some fail not long after.  But still, library code or not, a complete example from someone or not, one step at a time.

Note this appears to be a stackoverflow question not an electronics stackexchange